# How to connect appwrire with flutterflow...?

Tags: android, flutter, custom-action, flutterflow, appwrite

I tried connecting my Flutterflow application to Appwrite via a custom action in Flutterflow, but an error message stated that the URL "import 'package:dart_appwrite/dart_appwrite.dart';" did not exist. I have attempted to use both dependencies "dart_appwrite: ~10.1.0 and appwrite: ~11.0.1"; could you perhaps help me find the correct path?

I tried connecting my Flutterflow application to Appwrite via a custom action in Flutterflow, but an error message stated that the URL "import 'package:dart_appwrite/dart_appwrite.dart';" did not exist. I have attempted to use both dependencies "dart_appwrite: ~10.1.0 and appwrite: ~11.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Not a Flutter/Dart expert here, but I did check the FlutterFlow documentation and seems like you must add your dependencies to your custom action in the following manner: https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/custom-functions/custom-actions#3.-add-dependency

Is this something you have done already?